# How can reduce the ionic 4 application load time?

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, ionic4

I want to improve my Ionic 4 application load time. It is taking time 6 seconds for app loading. my config.xml file is given below

```
   <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="100" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="500" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

these plugins that i am using into my application which is given below

```
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "cordova-fabric-plugin": {
        "FABRIC_API_KEY": "XXX",
        "FABRIC_API_SECRET": "XXX"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
```

please help me to solve it

Comment: Heavily related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37906054/5730444

Answer (score 0):

My advices for you is to

- move any code you in your first page's constructor to `ionViewDidLoad` if it's possible ofc.
- Build and run your app using the prod and release mode, you will notice the difference (by adding --prod and --release) 
  **Note**:the release build may not work for you, for android you need to install the app from the google play store.
- Also try to optimise all the parts of your app, pictures, any media that you are using.
- updating the plugins will enhance the performance as well (because there is always bugs fixing and code optimisations in the new versions).
  I believe if you applied all the above advices, the loading time will be decreased significantly as well as the app's performance.