# Accelerate Cordova-packaged application load time

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, startup

I am building a native mobile application using Ext JS 6.2 modern toolkit + Cordova native packaging. I also use CrossWalk Chromium plugin instead of native webview.

The application requires about 10 seconds to load (i.e. to see its interface after Cordova splash screen) on a mid-range mobile phone (Samsung A5). I optimized it to do all Ajax connections after the appearance of the interface. So, this time is really required to load and initialize the framework.

Is there a way to minimize this time? Are there any recommendations to do so? Maybe a plugin or option to lazy-load the required framework classes? Any start-up optimization suggestion regarding Cordova and/or Sencha Ext JS is welcomed.

Comment: 10s ? That's really a lot but depends on the size of your app. I assume that you are building your app using Sencha Cmd right?

Comment: @pagep Yes, I use Sencha Cmd to build the app. The app is big and uses a lot of Cordova plugins (imagine it as WhatsApp).

Comment: As hard as it might be: Try to reduce the number of plugins...

Comment: Those questions might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925297/how-fast-typical-phonegap-app-can-be-started-tips-to-speed-up and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896070/decrease-loading-time-from-coldstart-in-cordova-ionic

Comment: @Phonolog Thanks. They are indeed helpful.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi: Are you loading app in dev mode or production build mode ?

Comment: there is no specific response i think, you need to make some js profiling on app to determine what framework (or plugin) cause this deelay. Try to mesure time from start to deviceready event, and gradually load all framework and plugins..

Comment: @Tejas1991 in production mode

Comment: @Frix33 Yeah apparently this is the only thing to do

Comment: I believe sencha takes to much to load. Even on web it takes too long, thats why I abandoned in favour of ionic with angular.